# How to pass URL from controller to Directive in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

```
angular.module('finalApp').controller('GetAgentDetailsCtrl', function ($scope,$rootScope){
    var vm=this;
    vm.url='api/agent/getAgentDetails';
});


'use strict';
angular.module('finalApp').directive('homeHeader',['HttpService',function(HttpService){
    return{
        restrict:'E',
        templateUrl:'views/directives/header/header.html',
        controller: 'GetAgentDetailsCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'GetAgentDetlCtrl',
        link: function ($scope) {
            HttpService.get(GetAgentDetlCtrl.url).success(function (data) {
                $scope.GetAgentDetlCtrl.defaultData = data;
                console.log($scope.GetAgentDetlCtrl.defaultData);
            });
        }
    };
}]);


<header ng-controller="GetAgentDetlCtrl">     
    {{GetAgentDetlCtrl.data}}
</header>

<main>
<home-header></home-header>
</main>
```

Comment: have you tried to google your headline? I guess ... as far as i see, you should stick to that plan, because the rest of your post is ... 

Try to find the introduction to angularjs from e.g. egghead.io. There are plenty of good tutorials and descriptions how to understand the way directives work. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('finalApp').controller('GetAgentDetailsCtrl', function ($scope,$rootScope){
    var vm=this;
    vm.url='api/agent/getAgentDetails';
});


'use strict';
angular.module('finalApp').directive('homeHeader',['HttpService',function(HttpService){
    return{
        restrict:'E',
        templateUrl:'views/directives/header/header.html',
        controller: 'GetAgentDetailsCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'GetAgentDetlCtrl',
        scope: {
         url : '='
        }
        link: function ($scope) {
            HttpService.get($scope.url).success(function (data) {
                $scope.GetAgentDetlCtrl.defaultData = data;
                console.log($scope.GetAgentDetlCtrl.defaultData);
            });
        }
    };
}]);


<header ng-controller="GetAgentDetlCtrl">     
    {{GetAgentDetlCtrl.data}}
</header>

<main>
<home-header url="http://yoursite.blah"></home-header>
</main>
```